# Bitwise operations with big integers

Tags: javascript, integer, bit-manipulation

I am implementing decoding of BER-compressed integers and recently I've found a weird JavaScript behavior related to bitwise operations with big integers.

E.g.:

```
var a = 17516032;          // has 25 bits
alert(a << 7)              // outputs -2052915200
alert(a * 128)             // outputs  2242052096
alert(2242052096 >> 16)    // outputs -31325
alert(2242052096 / 65536)  // outputs  34211
```

While the first workaround (multiplication instead of left shift) is acceptable, the second isn't.

Why it happens? How to bear with it?

Comment: I don't undestand why the division would not be acceptable?

Comment: @Guffa I need some general approach, not only for 32 bit integers.

Comment: Division isn't performed on integers, it's performed on floating point numbers, so I don't understand your argument. Besides, a double precision floating point number can only represent a 53 bit integer, so that's not much anyway if you want to decode BER-compressed numbers.

Comment: @Guffa I need hight 16 bits of an integers. Division by 65536 won't work well if number is not dividable by 65536 (sure, I can do Math.floor(x / 65536) but it doesn't look nice).

Comment: So you just want something that does the same thing, but looks differently?

Comment: How about `~~(x*152587890625e-16)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`17516032` in binary is `00000001000010110100011000000000`. Shifting to the left by 7 gives you `10000101101000110000000000000000`. This is equal to `-2052915200` in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (which is how almost all computers represent negative numbers).

`>>` is a signed right shift. That means that the leftmost bit (which determines the sign of a number) will be shifted into the left side.

e.g.

```
1100 >> 2 == 1111
0111 >> 2 == 0001
```

If you want to do an unsigned shift (which ignores the sign bit), use `>>>` which will zero-fill the left end of the bitstring.

Comment: That's it, thanks!  Any idea why left shift produces such strange result?

Comment: No problem. Edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 6):

Bitwise operators work on 32 bit integers, while multiplication and division works on floating point numbers.

When you shift a number, it's converted from a floating point number to a 32 bit integer before the operations, and converted back to a floating point number after the operation. The number 2242052096 has the 32nd bit set, so it is a negative number when converted to and from a 32 bit integer.

The `>>` right shift operator doesn't change the sign of the value, i.e. the bits that are shifted in from the left have the same value as the sign bit. Use the `>>>` right shift operator to shift in zero bits instead.

Reference: [MDN: Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 2):

`(2242052096 / 65536) == (2242052096 >>> 16)`

Note the different shift.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript normally represents numbers as (double-precision) floating point.

Almost all bitwise operations convert to a signed 32-bit integer, do whatever they're going to do, then treat the result as a signed 32-bit integer when converting back.

The exception is `>>>` which treats the result as an *unsigned* 32-bit integer when converting back.

So:

- right shifts can be made to work simply by using `>>>` instead of `>>` ;
- `a * 128` gives the expected answer because it's never converted to a signed 32-bit integer in the first place - it's just a floating-point multiplication;
- `a << 7` gives an unexpected answer because it's converted to a signed 32-bit integer, and then you shift a  `1` into the sign bit, resulting in a negative signed 32-bit value.

There isn't a `<<<`, but if you want to write your left shift as a shift, you can use

```
(a << 7) >>> 0
```

to get the expected answer (the `>>> 0` effectively casts the signed 32-bit value to an unsigned 32-bit value).