# Conversion of a hash function from C# to Javascript has issues with bitwise math

Tags: c#, javascript, hash, bit-shift

I've got the following C# hash function (also found on SO!), which I'm using in a bunch of apps covering a few different platforms:

```
public static int GetStableHash(string s, int hashlength)
{
    uint hash = 0;
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        hash += b;
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    // final avalanche
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);

    return (int)(hash % hashlength);
}
```

I'm trying to port it to Javascript, where another app will be generating matching hashes. Only problem is that JS doesn't have a uint type, and appears to convert ints to floats internally before performing bitwise math anyway. This is causing a problem with this ported function:

```
function getStableHash(s, hashlength)
{
    var hash = 0;
    var bytes = stringToBytes(s);   // this function just grabs a byte array for the given input string
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    {
        hash += bytes[i];
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    // final avalanche
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);

    return Math.round(hash % hashlength);
}
```

In the above code, the shifts end up causing problems due to the presence of the signing bit, and the resulting hash doesn't match the output of the C# version. It's unclear from various other SO posts (see [Bitwise operations with big integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847636/bitwise-operations-with-big-integers) for example) what the best way to resolve this would be.

There's already code in production using the hash method in C# and C++, so it's not an option to change the hash method elsewhere to accomodate Javascript's shortcomings.

How can I work around JS's internal type conversions?

Comment: it's the other way around - JS converts all numbers (which are internally the same as IEE748 `doubles`) into 32-bit (signed) ints for bitwise operations.

Comment: p.s. please show some sample inputs and outputs from the C# code.

Comment: @Alnitak: Sure - good idea! In C#, the hash of "ABC123" with hashlength 1000000 is 276076. "StackOverflow"  with hashlength 1000000 is 510536. "StackOverflow" with hashlength 1000 is 536.

Comment: that should of course have read IEEE754.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Use an unsigned right shift `>>>` instead of signed
2. Use `>>> 0` to convert the final result into an *unsigned* 32 bit int before taking the modulo:

   `return (hash >>> 0) % hashlength;`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It was that final unsigned rightshift which did the trick.